# Access elements interface/implementation Java

Tags: java, interface, implementation

I'm getting some using the interface/implementation in Java.

I have to use interfaces and implementations. For instance, if I want to calculate the intersection of two sets, I have to call the method on the first set with argument the second set, e.g. set1.intersect(set2).

This is my interface:

```
SetInterface intersect(SetInterface set);
    /* PRE
     * POST
     */
```

and this is the implementation:

```
public SetInterface intersect(SetInterface set) {
        intersectCounter = 0;
        Set intersectionSet = new Set();

        for (int i = 0; i <= set.size(); i++) {
            for (int j = 0; j <= set.size(); j++) {
                if (identifiers[i].identical(set.identifiers[j])) {
                        intersectionSet.identifiers[intersectCounter] = identifiers[i];
                        intersectCounter++;
                }

            }
        }
        return intersectionSet;
    }
```

I can't get access to the *set.identifiers[j]*.

What I'm doing wrong?

Comment: Can you please show the full declarations of the interface and classes?

Comment: `Set` has no `identifiers` method.

Comment: if `Set` in your code is `java.util.Set` then this is wrong `Set intersectionSet = new Set();` you cannot instantiate that interface. Also you should provide more information about the error you're getting. Also if Set is something you've written - add its code as well.

Comment: did you define `Set` by yourself or using the java library's `Set`?